# What is the point of the ''@localhost user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, permissions

Quoting MySQL docs:

> If you cannot figure out why you get Access denied, remove from the
>   user table all entries that have Host values containing wildcards
>   (entries that contain '%' or '_' characters). A very common error is
>   to insert a new entry with Host='%' and User='some_user', thinking
>   that this enables you to specify localhost to connect from the same
>   machine. The reason that this does not work is that the default
>   privileges include an entry with Host='localhost' and User=''. Because
>   that entry has a Host value 'localhost' that is more specific than
>   '%', it is used in preference to the new entry when connecting from
>   localhost! The correct procedure is to insert a second entry with
>   Host='localhost' and User='some_user', or to delete the entry with
>   Host='localhost' and User=''.

What I can't understand is why is this entry there in the first place? I fail to come up with any purpose they could serve.

Could I have potentially broken something by deleting them? (One of the suggested actions in the quote above)

**Note:** I know there are multiple questions asking why user@'%' won't work and answers containing this exact quote. What I want to know is why is this problem(?) created in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anonymous account and can be used for various purposes where you don't want to have to specify a username and password, such as within a script.

Granted this is a security hole but is also limited to being on the localhost. You could also alter the grant privileges of this anonymous account so that it can only do selects on a particular database or even single table.